# Give material card width as parent in inline div

Tags: html, css, angular6, angular-material-6

I am making a three columns inline div and adding a mat-card in the left. While doing so, due to relative position of mat-card, the div shifts to bottom. And on doing position absolute, the mat-card comes in the position as I wanted, however the width is not adjusted as parent. Can anyone help me ?

This is my HTML

```
<div id='main'>
  <div [style.background]="'blue'" id='components'>
    <mat-card>
        <mat-card-title>Components</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-content>Inside it</mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>

  </div>
  <div [style.background]="'white'" id='preview'>
  </div>
  <div [style.background]="'red'" id='properties'>
  </div>
</div>
```

And css

```
#main{
    height:calc(100vh - 64px);

    #components{
    width:30% !important;
    display: inline-block;
    height:100%;
    }

   #preview{
    width:40% !important;
    display: inline-block;
    height:100%;
   }

   #properties{
    width:30% !important;
    display: inline-block;
    height:100%;
    }
}
mat-card{
position:absolute;
}
```

The following is the output 
[image]

I want to have the card adjusted in the left div.

Please help me !!!!!

Comment: Please tell me the exact position where you want your mat card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for now I aligned your mat card to the bootom of the div and its taking 100% width of the parent, Tell me the position where you want the mat card, I will improve the answer.

```css
#main{
    height:calc(100vh - 64px);
}
    #components{
    width: 30% !important;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    }
    mat-card {
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
  }

   #preview {
    width: 40% !important;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}

   #properties {
    width: 30% !important;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}
}
```

```html
<div id='main'>
  <div [style.background]="'blue'" id='components'>
    <mat-card>
        <mat-card-title>Components</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-content>Inside it</mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>

  </div>
  <div [style.background]="'white'" id='preview'>
  </div>
  <div [style.background]="'red'" id='properties'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked however the card remains at the bottom, and your solution in the lower one did not work for the mat-card, the card was still overflown to the red div. Would you please tell me to position the component to top without using "position"?

Comment: OK this will work if the **align-item** is set to **flex-start** instead of **flex-end** in **component**.

Comment: yes, use flex-start, and the solution which I gave below will work, but you need to give position relative to first div Ie. parent of mat card. and if any of these help please mark that answer right. Thanks

Comment: i have marked as done, can you make the align-item to flex-start ?

Answer (score 0):

another solution for you without using flex and only position absolute. check this.

```css
#main{
    height:calc(100vh - 64px);
}
    #components{
    width: 30% !important;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    position: relative;
    }
    mat-card {
    width: 100%;
      display: block;
    background: yellow;
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
  }

   #preview {
    width: 40% !important;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}

   #properties {
    width: 30% !important;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id='main'>
  <div [style.background]="'blue'" id='components'>
    <mat-card>
        <mat-card-title>Components</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-content>Inside it</mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>

  </div>
  <div [style.background]="'white'" id='preview'>
  </div>
  <div [style.background]="'red'" id='properties'>
  </div>
</div>
```